# How to update <p:inputText> via ajax

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using primefaces 3.2

While the user paginate I want to update the globalFiler value

The attach code is not working :

```
       rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                 rows="10"
                 widgetVar="objectTable">
        <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{bean.onPaginate}" update="globalFilter"/>
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <p:outputPanel style="float: right">  
                <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                             value="#{bean.globalFilter}" 
                             onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {objectTable.filter()}" 
                             style="width:150px"/>
            </p:outputPanel>  
        </f:facet>
```

bean code:

```
public void onPaginate(PageEvent event){
     globalFilter = "test";
}
```

Any idea why the input text value is not updated ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for [PFS (PrimeFaces Selectors)](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf) I think its out since 3.3 (not sure)

instead of `update="globalFilter"` try update="@(.mySpecialFilter)"

and add to your `<p:inputText id="globalFilter"....` `styleClass="mySpecialFilter"`

it should work (in theory at least...)

Comment: If its possible try latest primefaces rls